# Vugen: Database connection failed from load runner

Tags: database, oracle, testing, vugen

I am using Vugen 1 version. I want to connect it to Oracle 11g. Someone could please mention the complete process for it as I did performance of web applications earlier. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ashwani. Your question is way too broad and doesn't show the smallest research background. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Unfortunately par for the course.  It is far too common that users of this tool are simply thrown at the tool without training and without a mentor with the demand to deliver.   As a result, they often are left with they don't know what they don't know and this impacts severely the ability to ask questions which are specific in nature

Answer (score 1):

The core question is whether it is an ORACLE problem or whether you have an installation issue with LoadRunner.  Fortunately, LoadRunner ships with sample applications which can be used as control elements to determine whether this is LoadRunner or ORACLE based.

Look to your sample applications.  Look for the FlightDB application.  This is an ODBC based application and will tell us if your LoadRunner application is installed correctly.  Record this application via ODBC.  If you cannot record the flights DB application successfully then this would point most likely to a failed installation or a failure to meet the credentials level required by the application.  Anti virus software can also be antagonistic to the ability to record, so disabling this may provide a benefit.

Only once the FlightDB application is working successfully should we turn back to the ORACLE application.  From there, start at a primitive level, with the SQL+ for Windows application.  This application is about as basic as one can get.   Record an ORACLE virtual user, using SQL+ for WIndows as the application.   Record a Sign on in the Init(), a query in the Action() and a logout in the End() sections of your test code.

IF that does not work, but the FlightsDB application does work, then it is time to look at your Oracle environment for issues. After using the control applications of FlightDB and the SQL+ for WIndows applications and having success, then turn back to your ORACLE application.   If you are still unable to record then you may have an application which is not architecturally as pure ORACLE as you may think.  Could it be a JDBC application, running in a Java environment?  Could it be an OLEDB connection?  Is it a .Net application?  All of these could potentially turn you towards a different route to build test code.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really too vague as already pointed out.

Anyway Oracle - 2 Tier Protocol is what you're looking for.

File -> New Script and Solution -> Oracle - 2 Tier. Record with sqlplus.exe (*C:\Program Files\ORACLI_X32\12.1.0\BIN* or *ORACLI_X64\12.1.0* depends on your installation).

Follow the instruction on the prompt screen (DB, Username, PW, Query, exit) and stop recording.